# How to ignore all after domain zone except symbol "/"

Tags: regex, string, perl, pcre

I have regex for match domain with username:

```
/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:facebook)\.com\/(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)$/
```

This regex match example URLs:

```
facebook.com/username
www.facebook.com/username
http://facebook.com/username
http://www.facebook.com/username
https://facebook.com/username
https://www.facebook.com/username
```

How change this regex for match only URLs with domain zone and non required symbol `/`:

```
facebook.com
facebook.com/
.....................
https://facebook.com/
https://www.facebook.com
```

Comment: So you are wanting to match string that only have the domain, with no forward slash at the end?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Only domain name with or without slash

Comment: Can you more clearly show which of the above 6 URLs should match, and then explain why that is the case?

Comment: And is this for Perl or PCRE? You've tagged both, but they are different things

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this should work `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/?$`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The above 6 URLs should not match. I only need a domain with or without slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only wanting to match strings that contain the domain only, then you can use something like this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/?$
```

This will match regardless if it has the protocol (`http(s):\/\/`) and regardless if it contains `www.`.

### [See it live](https://regex101.com/r/5kNnEu/1/)

Breaking down the regular expression, `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/?$`

- `^` start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` a non-capturing group that will match the protocol `https?:\/\/`, zero or one time `?` (optional)
- `(?:www\.)?` non-capturing group that will match on `www.`, zero or one time `?` (optional)
- `facebook\.com` will match the domain
- `\/?` will match an optional `?` forward slash `\/`
- `$` **end of string** <sub>(emphasis added)</sub> - this is what allows this to work with your requirements as this will not allow anything to match after the optional forward slash in the prior bullet.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged Perl, a Perl answer is to use a URI-parsing module such as [URI](http://metacpan.org/pod/URI) or [Mojo::URL](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::URL;
while (my $input = <<>>) { # or whatever way the input comes in
  chomp $input;
  my $url = Mojo::URL->new($input);
  next unless !defined $url->scheme or $url->scheme eq 'http' or $url->scheme eq 'https';
  next unless defined $url->host and ($url->host eq 'facebook.com' or $url->host eq 'www.facebook.com');
  next if length $url->path and $url->path ne '/';
  print "$input\n";
}
```